# Тип данных с ограниченным количество значений

Tags: c++

Как сделать такой тип данных, в котором будет ограниченное количество значений?
Например:

- bool, что может быть только true или false
- тип данных месяц, только 12 значений, от января до декабря

Comment: Что такое стоимости? Судя по примерам, речь идет о допустимых значениях.

Comment: «value» в данном случае переводится как «значение», а не «стоимость».

Comment: Сорян, просто учусь далеко не на русском языке.

Answer (score 1):

Для определения перечисления служит ключевое слово enum, а имена элементов задаются в фигурных скобках, через запятую. По умолчанию первый из них равен 0, следующий – 1 и так далее. С помощью оператора присваивания это правило можно изменить. При этом каждый следующий элемент без явно указанного значения будет на 1 больше, чем элемент, идущий перед ним в списке. В нашем примере мы явно указали значение 1 для input, при этом output и append будут равны 2 и 3. Вот еще один пример:

// shape == 0, sphere == 1, cylinder == 2, polygon == 3
enum Forms{ share, spere, cylinder, polygon };

Но по факту там будут значения от 0 до 3 например.
Ну можно добавить массив со значениями для них и тогда будет нормально.

Comment: Кроме перечислений, есть варианты?

Comment: вариантов много. Скажите конкретно что вам нужно

Comment: Ну мне надо в классе добавить тип данных "категория" и я не хочу, чтобы это был обычный стриг. Класс под названием "продукт" (как продукт я выбрал телефон)

Comment: enum не налагает никаких ограничений на диапазон хранимых значений, он полностью соответствует диапазону у соответствующего целочисленного типа.

Answer (score 0):

Класс прдставлющий числа от `1` по `H`

```
template <int H>
class Range {
    int  n;
public:
    Range(int k) : n(k%H + 1) {}
    Range& operator =(int k) { n = k%H + 1; return *this; }
    operator int() { return n; }
};
```

Телефон как продукт

```
struct Phone {string name{"Nokia"}; //...};
template <class P = Phone>
struct Product {
    P obj;
    //...
    operator P() { return obj; }
};

int main()
{    
    Product<> pr; // cодержит телефон
    //  pr это телефон
    cout << Phone(pr).name;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: unsigned int  для Range, более подходящий тип